# Why a member function in a class template creates the same object in the same address

Tags: c++11, templates, c++14, move, perfect-forwarding

I am working on testing a lock-free work-stealing queue I wrote recently. However, I found a weird issue, that when I push a new item to the queue, it only returns me the same object that was pushed at the last. It took me one day and I still cannot figure out why this happened. 
This is the output, every time, the data is the same to be pushed to the queue, which is why I only have the last result being 45, it should be all 45 for the 4 res items. Anybody can help me here :(

- push_back addr: 0x21d3ea0 bk: 0 &data: 0x7ffe36802380
- push_back addr: 0x21d3ea4 bk: 0 &data: 0x7ffe36802380
- push_back addr: 0x21d3ea8 bk: 0 &data: 0x7ffe36802380
- push_back addr: 0x21d3eac bk: 0 &data: 0x7ffe36802380
- res[0]=-1
- res[1]=-1
- res[2]=-1
- res[3]=45

Below is the simplified code:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

class FunctionWrapper {
private:
    class ImplInterface {
    public:
        virtual void invoke() = 0;
        virtual ~ImplInterface() {}
    };

    std::unique_ptr<ImplInterface> impl;

    template <typename F, typename... Args>
    class Impl : public ImplInterface {
    private:
        std::function<void()> callBack;
    public:
        Impl(F&& f_, Args&&... args_) {
            callBack = [&f_, &args_...]() { f_(std::forward<Args>(args_)...); };
        }

        void invoke() override { callBack(); } 
    };

public: 
    template <typename F, typename... Args>
    FunctionWrapper(F&& f_, Args&&... args_) : impl(new Impl<F, Args...>(std::forward<F>(f_), std::forward<Args>(args_)...)) {}

    void operator()() { impl->invoke(); }

    FunctionWrapper() = default;
    FunctionWrapper(FunctionWrapper&& other) : impl(std::move(other.impl)) {}
    FunctionWrapper& operator=(FunctionWrapper&& other) {
        impl = std::move(other.impl);
        return *this;
    }

    FunctionWrapper(const FunctionWrapper&) = delete;
    FunctionWrapper(FunctionWrapper&) = delete;
    FunctionWrapper& operator=(const FunctionWrapper&) = delete;
};
```

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <array>

#include <iostream>

#include "functionwrapper.h"

class LockFreeWorkStealingQueue {
private:
    using DataType = FunctionWrapper;
    static constexpr auto DEFAULT_COUNT = 2048u;
    static constexpr auto MASK = DEFAULT_COUNT - 1u;
    std::array<DataType, DEFAULT_COUNT> q;
    unsigned int ft{0};
    unsigned int bk{0};
public:
    LockFreeWorkStealingQueue() {}
    LockFreeWorkStealingQueue(const LockFreeWorkStealingQueue&) = delete;
    LockFreeWorkStealingQueue& operator=(const LockFreeWorkStealingQueue&) = delete;

    void push_back(DataType data) {
        std::cout << "bk: " << (bk&MASK) << " &data: " << &data << std::endl;
        q[bk & MASK] = std::move(data);
        bk++;
    }

    bool try_pop_back(DataType& res) {
        if (bk > ft) {
            res = std::move(q[(bk - 1) & MASK]);
            bk--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};
```

```cpp
#include "lockfreeworkstealingqueue.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

constexpr unsigned int NUM = 4;

void sumOver(const std::vector<int>& v, int& res) {
    res = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    //std::cout << "call sumOver, res = " << res << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "call sumOver, addr: "  << &res << std::endl;
}

int main () {
    std::vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    std::vector<int> res(NUM, -1);
    std::vector<LockFreeWorkStealingQueue> wsq(4);

    {

        for (auto i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (auto j = 0; j < NUM / 4; ++j) {
                std::cout << "push_back addr: " << &res[i*(NUM/4)+j] << std::endl;
                wsq[i].push_back(FunctionWrapper(sumOver, std::ref(v), std::ref(res.at(i*(NUM/4)+j)))); 
            }
        }

        FunctionWrapper f;
        for (auto i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (auto j = 0; j < NUM / 4; ++j) {
                if(wsq[i].try_pop_back(f)) {
                    f();
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < NUM / 4; ++j) {
            std::cout << "res[" << i*(NUM/4)+j << "]=" << res[i*(NUM/4)+j] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I made a change to functionwrapper.h to refect on the comments. and now it works well.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class FunctionWrapper {
private:
    std::function<void()> callback;
public: 
    template <typename F, typename... Args>
    FunctionWrapper(F&& f_, Args&&... args_) : callback([f_, args_...]() { f_(args_...); }) {}

    void operator()() { callback(); }

    FunctionWrapper() = default;
    FunctionWrapper(FunctionWrapper&& other) : callback(std::move(other.callback)) {}
    FunctionWrapper& operator=(FunctionWrapper&& other) {
        callback = std::move(other.callback);
        return *this;
    }

    FunctionWrapper(const FunctionWrapper&) = delete;
    FunctionWrapper(FunctionWrapper&) = delete;
    FunctionWrapper& operator=(const FunctionWrapper&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: `Impl` captures rvalues by reference. Those references can easily become dangling. I haven't read far enough to see if that actually happens in the code shown, but that's something to look out for. Why are you piling type erasure on top of type erasure, anyway? Why not have `FunctionWrapper` have `std::function` member directly?

Comment: This is hardly a [mcve]. But I see you pushing pointers to elements in a fixed-length `std::array`, so why wouldn't you expect the same memory addresses to be reused over time? Also, in your output message, `&data` is the address of a **local variable** on the call stack, which definitely gets reused over time. It might make more sense to output the address of `q[bk & MASK]` instead of `data`, since that is where you are storing `data`.

Comment: I don't know, it seems if I use std::function directly, then I cannot store it by pushing back to the queue with the function and all arguments, and then call it when I pop out it. Also I do not wanna the FunctionWrapper as a template when I declared it in other parts. I don't know how could I do this in aother way... @Igor Tandetnik

Comment: `template <typename F, typename... Args> FunctionWrapper(F&& f_, Args&&... args_) : callback([f_, args_...]() { f_(args_...); } {}`. I don't quite grasp the nature of the difficulty you are talking about. You made `Impl` a class template for no good reason - its member `callback` doesn't in fact depend on its template parameters.

Comment: Ahh, make sense. How could I initialize `callback` if I declare it as `unique_ptr<std::function<void()>> callback`? I am trying to create `FunctionWrapper` as move-only. @IgorTandetnik

Comment: Declare copy constructor and copy assignment operator as deleted, and the type will be move-only. I don't see why this requires holding `callback` by `unique_ptr`. But if you insist: `callback(std::make_unique<std::function<void()>>([f_, args_...]() { f_(args_...); }))`

Comment: Yeah... I guess I am a little stupid sometimes, lol. Thanks @IgorTandetnik I have added the code to reflect on your comments :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda in `FunctionWrapper::Impl` captures references to temporary `std::reference_wrapper` instances (produced by `std::ref` calls in `main`). By the time the lambda is actually called, those temporaries have long been destroyed and the references are dangling. Whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing objects whose lifetime has ended.

You want to capture by value instead, as in

```
Impl(F&& f_, Args&&... args_) {
  callBack = [f_, args_...]() { f_(args_...); };
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/OKS68577)

Comment: MANY THANKS!!! That is the problem. Ahh, I always tell myself to pay attention to the dangle pointers when using lambda. Still making mistakes..